# When are Tezos Rewards Unfrozen?

Tags: baker, rewards, endorser

When are the baking and endorsing rewards earned by a delegator unfrozen by the protocol?

Looking at the [Tezos docs](http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#security-deposits) I see the lockup for a security deposit is `PRESERVED_CYCLES` (5) but it makes no mention of the lockup for rewards.

Comment: The link "http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html#security-deposits" does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The lockup for rewards is the same - i.e. rewards are released when the security deposits are.